# Problems with fieldset absolute positioning

Tags: html, webforms

I'm coding a windows program which is a WYSIWYG form generator.

In a very simple test I placed a `fieldset` and dropped a checkbox and a text input field onto it.

The generated HTML looks fine when I read it, but it displays wrongly in Firefox, MSIE & K-meleon (which I think has an FFF engine).  The fieldset height does no seem to be rendering correctly.

I also tried removing the `height` attribute to see if the fieldset would wrap around its child controls, but it looked the same in the browser. Probably a mistake in my HTML, I guess, but I can't spot it...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="C:\temp\aa.php" method="get">
<div class="TGroupBox" id="GroupBox1" style="position: absolute; top:32px; left:32px; width: 185px; height: 105px;">
<fieldset>
<legend>GroupBox1</legend>
<div class="TCheckBox" id="CheckBox1" style="position: absolute; top:24px; left: 16px; width: 97px; height: 17px;"><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" value="CheckBox1Checked"></div>
<div class="TEdit" id="Edit1" style="position: absolute; top:64px; left: 16px; width: 121px; height: 21px;"><input type="text" name="Edit1"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because elements inside your fieldset are all *absolutely positioned*, and out of content flow. Fieldset just **collapses to empty content**.

So you need to manually set fieldset's height to 105px (equal to parent div's height).

Comment: sorry to be so stupid - I am no HTML guru.   Do youmean I should move the position details from the div to the fildset?  Can you post an example?   I am not so sure, because not I have the same problem with a `textare` but maybe it is because I put the position in the div and not in the textarea?   Thanks for your help

Comment: ok, I figured it out - don't put the poition stuff on the div, put it on the controls which the div encloses. Thanks.

Comment: <fieldset style="height:105px">